# Fraction macro in lyx

Tags: macros, lyx, fractions

I want to create a macro for word-like fraction sign in lyx. Namely, when I write `1/2` I want it to be `\frac{1}{2}`

Any Ideas?

Comment: And if you write `13/5` it should be `\frac{13}{5}` or `1\frac{3}{5}`? Or something else?

Comment: I guess `\frac{13}{5}`

Comment: So what about `\sin1/2`? (I want to show you potential problems).

Comment: that should be `\frac{\sin1}{2}`.I know it does not cover all the cases in the world, but I find it much easier to use this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it even more easily - create a macro of `\frac{#1}{#2}` and then you could just press `Tab` to move between the two arguments (#1, #2).

What you want requires special parsing (reading of text and doing something based on , which is not possible, as far as I know, with regular macros.

Comment: Did I answer your question? If so, please don't forget to accept my answer. :)